# Why does ag-grid code appears in my stenciljs component bundle?

Tags: optimization, build, ag-grid, web-component, stenciljs

I am trying to optimize a StencilJS component that uses ag-grid as third party dependency. Currently, rollup is adding ag-grid definitions to my bundle of code resulting in ~1Mb bundle size (archived).

Is there a way to achieve code separation in my bundle? or am I looking at things in the wrong way?

This component is used in a vue app alongside other 3rd party web component that also uses ag-grid. The ag-grid code will be duplicated in this scenario.
The component library is fairly simple with only 2 ts components:

```
$ ls -l src/components/product-picker/
total 30
-rw-r--r-- 1 197121  1692 Aug  8 10:35 readme.md
-rw-r--r-- 1 197121    41 Jul  9 13:38 product-filter.scss
-rw-r--r-- 1 197121  6521 Jul 19 09:34 product-filter.tsx
-rw-r--r-- 1 197121   371 Jun 25 11:51 product-picker.scss
-rw-r--r-- 1 197121 10089 Aug  8 10:21 product-picker.tsx
-rw-r--r-- 1 197121  1630 Jul 15 17:00 product-picker-grid.scss
drwxr-xr-x 1 197121     0 Jun 25 11:51 test/
```

This is how I import the ag-grid in my tsx component

```
import { ModuleRegistry } from '@ag-grid-community/core';
import { ClientSideRowModelModule } from '@ag-grid-community/client-side-row-model';
import { Grid, GridOptions } from '@ag-grid-community/core';
[...]

ModuleRegistry.registerModules([
  ClientSideRowModelModule,
]);

@Component({
  tag: 'product-picker',
  styleUrl: 'product-picker.scss',
})
```

This is how the build files looks like:

```
$ ls -lh dist/esm/
total 2.2M
-rw-r--r-- 1 197121    1 Aug  8 10:35 index.js
-rw-r--r-- 1 197121  41K Aug  8 10:35 index-0f6f2d39.js
-rw-r--r-- 1 197121  931 Aug  8 10:35 loader.js
drwxr-xr-x 1 197121    0 Aug  8 10:35 polyfills/
-rw-r--r-- 1 197121 2.2M Aug  8 10:35 product-filter_2.entry.js
-rw-r--r-- 1 197121  947 Aug  8 10:35 product-picker.js
```

The `product-filter_2.entry.js` file has all the lines of code related to ag-grid.

Answer (score 0):

#### Option 1

You could try using Typescript 3.8's [type only imports](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-8.html) :

That way, you get the type safety of TS, without including all of `ag-grid` in your Stencil bundle. This assumes that some other component on the page does include `ag-grid` in a way that makes it accessible to your Stencil component

#### Option 2

If you're using webpack you could consider marking `ag-grid` as an `external` library, not to be included in the generated bundle.

There's a similar question around not bundling the React runtime with every component, and instead adding it just once on the page with a script tag to reduce bundle sizes.

https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/1275#issuecomment-123846260

```
{
        ...
        externals: {
            // Use external version of React
            "react": "React"
        },
       ...
}
```

#### Option 3

You could *not* add `ag-grid` as a dependency to your Stencil project and instead rely on the existence of `window.agGrid` or something similar. Personally I dislike that option because at this point, you get no type safety in your Stencil project.

Comment: thank you so much for your answer. I will give it a pass at option 2, that one seems the best option for me.

Comment: Glad I could help. Please consider marking the answer as accepted if it meets your need :)